# AngularJS validation referencing form object with variable name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-validation

Let's say I have a simple form with some Angular validation:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input name="{{myField}}" 
            type="text" 
            ng-model="obj.myField" 
            required />
    <div class="text-danger" ng-show="myForm[myField].$invalid">
        <div ng-show="myForm[myField].$error.required">
            Field is required.
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Now let's say I want to use a variable for the form name instead of a hard-coded string:

```
<form name="{{formName}}">
```

How can I modify `myForm[myField].$invalid` and `myForm[myField].$error.required` to still reference my form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the current angular, you cannot have dynamically named form input elements. If you are doing this over a collection of forms, you can use the `ng-form` directive and do something like this (in jade syntax):

```
div(ng-repeat = "user in users", class="form-group")
    ng-form(name="userFieldForm")
      input(type="text", required, ng-model="user.email", name="email")
      p(class="help-block" ng-show="userFieldForm.email.$invalid">Valid Email Address required
```